# Create issue with custom field by JIRA API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to create an issue using Jira REST API. Below code will works to create simple issue:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue' \
  --user 'user:token' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data {
    "fields": {
      "summary": "Remote test with request type",
      "issuetype": {
        "id": "12542"
        },
      "project": {
        "key": "Test"
        },
      "description": {
        "type": "doc",
        "version": 1,
        "content": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "text": "Second remote test",
                "type": "text"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The thing is I want to create an issue with custom field - `customfield_10029`. By default it's set as nil but when I changed it manually in my board I saw something few more things inside of it:

```
  "customfield_10029":
  {"_links": {"jiraRest": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/241495", "web": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/19/SUP-11", "self": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request/241495"},
   "requestType":
    {"_expands": ["field"],
     "id": "358",
     "_links": {"self": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/19/requesttype/358"},
     "name": "Add Colaborator / Team Member",
     "description": "e.g. external dev",
     "helpText": "you can find github nicks down here https://github.com/some_url",
     "issueTypeId": "12542",
     "serviceDeskId": "19",
     "groupIds": ["70"],
     "icon":
      {"id": "19558",
       "_links":
        {"iconUrls":
          {"48x48": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=large",
           "24x24": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=small",
           "16x16": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=xsmall",
           "32x32": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=medium"}}}}
```

So I thought the only thing I need to do is to add above code to the first POST request, like below:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue' \
  --user 'user:token' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data {
    "fields": {
      "summary": "Remote test with request type",
      "issuetype": {
        "id": "12542"
        },
      "project": {
        "key": "SUP"
        },
      "description": {
        "type": "doc",
        "version": 1,
        "content": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "text": "Second remote test",
                "type": "text"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "customfield_10029":
      {"_links": {"jiraRest": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/241495", "web": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/19/SUP-11", "self": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request/241495"},
       "requestType":
        {"_expands": ["field"],
         "id": "358",
         "_links": {"self": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/19/requesttype/358"},
         "name": "Add Colaborator / Team Member",
         "description": "e.g. external dev",
         "helpText": "you can find github nicks down here https://github.com/some_url",
         "issueTypeId": "12542",
         "serviceDeskId": "19",
         "groupIds": ["70"],
         "icon":
          {"id": "19558",
           "_links":
            {"iconUrls":
              {"48x48": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=large",
               "24x24": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=small",
               "16x16": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=xsmall",
               "32x32": "https://company_name.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?avatarType=SD_REQTYPE&avatarId=19558&size=medium"}}}}
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
{"errorMessages":["Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@2e2743e7; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@2e2743e7; line: 46, column: 1863]"]}
```

Is there any logic behind that? how to create such an issue with customfield?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a brace.

```
--data {  #<- This brace has no closing brace
"fields": { #<- This brace closes with the very last brace
```